# How to achieve this desired output?

Tags: c++

I may sound repetitive from previous posts, but I keep running into issues. My goal is to get my current code to print out a reflection of what I currently have.

Here is the sample of code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfDolls = 0;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;
    
    // Increment the proper number of dolls.  
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 1, n = numberOfDolls; j <= i; j++)
      { 
        cout << setw(n--) << '/' << endl;
      }
      for (int k = 1, s = numberOfDolls - i + 1; k <= i; k++)
      {
        cout << setw(s++) << '\\' << endl;
      }
      cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 1) << "-" << endl;
    } 
}
```

If the user enters 3, it prints this:

```
   /
   \
    -
   /
  /
  \ 
   \
    -
   /
  /
 /
 \
  \
   \
    -
```

I need the final product to look like the following.

```
   /   \
    \ /
     -

   /   \
  /     \
   \   /
    \ /
     -
  
   /   \ 
  /     \
 /       \
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     -
```

This may be a bit confusing to understand, please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo alright im trying to get in within the code I had but no success, I havent learned much cpp so it is difficult.

Comment: It might help to think about how you would print two vertical parallel lines and then once you have that work on varying the distance between them and using the proper characters.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i updated it. Still stuck, i feel like im just doing more damage

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure how to even get the flawed half shape based on the way my code is set up. I am sorry for the dumb questions, I'm new. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Alright, i'll get back to u when i get it

Comment: @TedLyngmo do I need to create a whole new loop or just add to my existing ones?

Comment: Sorry for dropping out, it was bedtime. Loops are not the only option. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/T646YdE5q)

Comment: I see, I haven't learned how to do it that way yet I believe I am supposed to use loops but that also makes sense.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could I use the 'cout' outputs you showed me in that example but also incorporate loops?

Comment: @wockywoad The calculation of how many spaces that are needed is all that matters really. You don't need a class like I used. Doing the same in a loop [1,3] will look very similar. I wrote that program by first drawing the graph on paper to come up with the actual numbers used. If you do the same, you'll come to a similar solution. You may name the magic numbers while doing it so they don't look quite as arbitrary as in my example though.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberOfDolls = 0;
    int deltaIndent = 0;
    int topMergin = 3;
    int botmMergin = 1;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;



    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {

        deltaIndent = numberOfDolls - i;
        for (int j=i; j>0 ;j--)
            cout << setw(j + deltaIndent) << '/' << setw(topMergin + (i-j) * 2 + 1) << '\\' <<endl;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
            cout << setw(j + deltaIndent + 1) << '\\' << setw(botmMergin + (i-j) * 2 + 1) << '/' << endl;

        cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 2) << "-" << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

output

```
Number of dolls -> 4
   /   \
    \ /
     -

   /   \
  /     \
   \   /
    \ /
     -

   /   \
  /     \
 /       \
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     -

   /   \
  /     \
 /       \
/         \
 \       /
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     -
```

Comment: just note avoid putting everything in main. It is good practice to define separate function for specific tasks. [See this refactoring](https://godbolt.org/z/6Kr5MKE1s) (your code just sliced into functions).